# Combining multiple assemblies into a single EXE for a WPF application

Tags: wpf, dll

I followed this tutorial to combine a few DLL's into my EXE.

http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application

The way I understand this works is:
- it starts by telling the compiler to embed (as embedded resources) each and every DLL that have their Local Copy set to True.

That part is working fine. It apparently doesn't "add" them as resources to my project (figure 1 in the tutorial kind of says otherwise), but I can tell that the size of my EXE is correct.

FYI, my program uses WPFtoolkit, in my case, that's 2 DLL's: 
system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit.dll
WPFToolkit.dll

Then, I set the Build Action of my App.xaml to Page, and made a program.cs file which I added to my project.

this is my project.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Shell;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Globalization;


namespace Swf_perium {


    public class Program {


        //[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        //[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        [STAThreadAttribute]
        public static void Main() {           
            Swft_perium.App app = new Swf_perium.App();                       
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnResolveAssembly;
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }

        private static Assembly OnResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {            
            Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
            string path = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            if (assemblyName.CultureInfo.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == false)
            {
                path = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", assemblyName.CultureInfo, path);
            }            
            using (Stream stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path))
            {
                if (stream == null)
                    return null;                
                byte[] assemblyRawBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyRawBytes, 0, assemblyRawBytes.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyRawBytes);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

After I build the project, I run it off VS2013, no problem, since both DLL's have their local copy set to true. If I go in my debug folder, take both DLL's out and run the EXE off windows explorer, then the program instantly crashes because it can find the DLL's.

What this tutorial should allow me to do is being able to run that EXE by itself without the DLL's, so yeah, it doesn't work.

I added a console writeline of the path that are being read by the OnResolveAssembly method of my program.cs. And here's what I get:
4 times the same path:
"Swf_perium.resources.dll"

Obviously, when it gets to the Stream, it's null and the method then returns null.

I am trying to understand where these paths are coming from? I don't understand why 4? And why this path?

Has anyone ever tried this technique? Comments on the blog show pretty good success rate.
Does anyone have an idea?

I made several mistakes to get to this stage, but at this point I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks
Steve

EDIT: following HB's guidance, here's what I did:

I took the MSBuild target "mod" out.
Set both references' copy local to FALSE.
Added both DLL as embedded resources manually. They're both into the "Resources" directory at the root of the project.
I set App.xaml build action back to "ApplicationDefinition".
And I excluded my program.cs out of the project.

and added this code to App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Swf_perium
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);       
        }

        private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            var execAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string resourceName = execAssembly.FullName.Split(',').First() + ".Resources." + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
            Console.WriteLine(resourceName);
            using (var stream = execAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

now, the console prints out of the 2 DLL's filename, but not the other.. I am guessing that's why it's still not working..

that's where I'm at.

edit:

The DLL that doesn't show is not called by my code directly. it's a dependence from the first DLL. I took that second DLL out of references and resources.. If I set copy local to true for the first DLL (which my program actually uses), building the project generates both DLL at the root - in this case with both dlls generated the program works, funny thing is if I delete that second DLL, the program still works. So the problem isn't that second DLL but the first one.

the error I have (which I've had all along no matter what technique I use) is that my XAML is calling that namespace and can't find it!

edit:

Ok, well it still doesn't work. I've brought my program.cs back into the solution, set it as the entry point. And added the code suggested by HB into it.
I made sure that the assemblyresolve is done on the first line of the main so that's it's done before any wpf is done. I even added a 5s sleep just to make sure that the dll was loaded before any wpf happens. Still no go.

Either the dependence to the second DLL is what's causing a problem (?) or maybe the way I import the namespace in my XAML is incorrect. Do I need to specify that this namespace is embedded? and where it's located - i.e. its path?.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) where it will do all the hard work of embedding assemblies for you.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but I'd really like to understand what's not working

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your project structure but i usually add a directory for the assemblies to the root of the project and then add the dlls to that directory as embedded resource. I also then turn off the local copy of the references to make sure that it works.

Here is the code i use in my `App.xaml.cs`:

```
static App()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}

private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var execAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string resourceName = execAssembly.FullName.Split(',').First() + ".ReferencedAssemblies." +
          new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
    using (var stream = execAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
    }
}
```

Simply replace the `".ReferencedAssemblies."` string according to the directory you placed the dlls in.

(Using the static constructor of the class makes sure that the event is hooked up before any code that potentially accesses referenced assemblies is executed, in your code i would move the hook to the first line of `Main`, that may already solve your problem.)

Comment: Thanks, just tried your technique. I just added a console.writeline(resourceName) to see where it's pointing at, and that's where I think the problem is (again!). it prints: Swf_perium.Resources.Swf_perium.resources.dll instead of the actual DLL's. It should be printing my 2 DLL's there, right? Btw, I've added both DLL as embedded resources, in the "Resources" directory at the root of the project.

Comment: Actually, it prints this (above) twice, the third (3 total, why 3?) is correct: Swf_perium.Resources.System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll I am missing the other dll: WPFToolkit.dll

Comment: @user3617652: The `<Assembly>.resources.dll` ones are automatically generated, don't worry about them. Just make sure the files have the same name as the assembly inside.

Comment: ok thank you for confirming that. Well, the filename is correct for the first DLL, but the second one isn't loaded at all. It's set to embedded resources and in the same folder. not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @user3617652: Is the second one actually in use anywhere in the project and does the project reference the assembly?

Comment: now that you mention it, I am not sure it is used. Both are referenced as references. The other one (which actually is printed out by the console) is called (imported) right in the XAML and is also called by a using in my code. So I guess that's why it doesn't show. let me take the reference out to see what happens.

Comment: Oh wow, here's a weird one. The second DLL (WPFToolkit.dll) is not used in my code, and not referenced anywhere. I took the reference out of the list. I build the project, and it does regenerate it next to my EXE. It's probably a dependence from the first DLL... I guess that's my problem?